# JPanel within a Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have created an Object that extends JPanel and draws beginning at (0,0) a short animation). It works great on its own but I would like to add a button above it to handle small actions for the animation.

So in my main class I did the following:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
JButton testButton = new Button("BUTTON");
MyAnimationDrawer drawing1 = new MyAnimationDrawer();
```

What i want to do:

[image]

How would I add the button and my Object to the JFrame so that the top left corner acts as (0,0)? Exactly as shown in my image link.

Comment: Add the button to your panel, then add the panel to your JFrame.

Comment: Ignore my above post, I thought you wanted drawing (0,0) to match frame (0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As brano88 has stated, the simplest way to achieve this is by using [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). Below is a short example of what you desire using this layout. As `BorderLayout` is the default layout manager for a JFrame, you do not need to explicitly set it, just use its fields out of the box.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)   {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My frame");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Button Panel
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Click me!"));

        //Drawing panel
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: when you set the BorderLayout as center, if nothing is to the left or right, I assume that it defaults to the entire screen

Comment: @user32081 Expands to the entire screen horizontally, yes.

Comment: Why use `paintComponent(...)` to set background color when a simple `setBackground(...)` call in the constructor is all that is needed? JPanel's are opaque by default and so this will work just fine for them.

Comment: Just for the OP's benefit. He is clearly doing some drawing so I stuck to that style, just incase OP wanted to also deal with a JComponent.

Comment: You should read about [concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Where does concurrency come into adding a JPanel onto a JFrame?

Answer (score 3):

By using [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Add `drawing panel` on `CENTER` of `JFrame`. Something like:

```
frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Add `button` on `upper panel` and then add `upper panel` on `NORTH` of `JFrame`:

```
upperPanel.add(button);
frame.add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```